# TreeSet custom comparator with long values

Tags: java, long-integer, comparator

I have a `TreeSet<MyObject>` where `MyObject` has a method `getID()`.

The `getID()` method returns a `long` which I want to use to sort the `MyObject`s within the custom comparator of a TreeSet

```
Comparator<MyObject> comparator = new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    public int compare(MyObject a0, MyObject a1) {
        return a0.getID()-a1.getID();
    }

};
TreeSet<MyObject> set = new TreeSet<MyObject>(comparator);
```

However the method `compare` must return an `int`and I'm comparing `long`s. Is there a way I can get around this?

Comment: Use some `if` statements to convert that into `-1`, `0`, and `1`, perhaps?

Comment: @user3580294 Such a simple solution! Why didn't I think of that!? Thanks a tonne!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magnitude of the difference is not important, simply that there is a difference.

```
long a0long = a0.getID();
long a1long = a1.getID();
if (a0long < a1long)
{
    return -1;
}

return a0long == a1long ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: @S.L. Barth I am not quite sure I follow your comment. This will cause the results to be sorted in order by id. It does not matter whether the comparator returns -99999999 or -1, both show that the first item is less than the second.

Answer (score 2):

How about just using the Long object?

```
Long.compare(a0.getID(),a1.getID());
```

Java doc:

```
public static int compare(long x,long y)

Compares two long values numerically. The value returned is identical to what would be returned by:

    Long.valueOf(x).compareTo(Long.valueOf(y))


Parameters:
    x - the first long to compare
    y - the second long to compare
Returns:
    the value 0 if x == y; a value less than 0 if x < y; and a value greater than 0 if x > y
Since:
    1.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line:

```
return Long.valueOf(a0.getID()).compareTo(Long.valueOf(a1.getID()));
```